# console.log does not work in frontend JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode and have node.js installed. When using console.log statements in the index.js file (backend), the output shows up in the debug console. However, when using a console.log statement in the script.js file the output doesn't show up.

The output doesn't appear in problems, output or terminal either

This is probably a really easy fix but does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Bit unclear what you're referring to when you say it's not appearing in `script.js`, or "in problems"? Can you please share some of your code for these files?

Comment: console.log in a browser (i.e frontend or client) script will appear in the **browser**s *developer* tools console. I'm not sure if there's a simple way to make them appear on the backend as well - perhaps [this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-bring-the-browser-devtools-and-console-to-vs-code-848edc257094) or [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging) will help, it's simple enough if you know what you are doing

Comment: It's important to understand that Javascript files that run in your web page are running in the browser on the client computer.  That is typically  not the same computer as the server and the console output will show in the browser console, not your server environment's console.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, node js is a backend language, so the stdout will be displayed in the VSC terminal output.

The console.log you use in the JavaScript file included in your webpage will be output in your browser console (or in your debug console if your run your project with it)

To use the debug console of VSC use this conf in your .vsccode/launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type":"chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug Front",
        "url": "http://localhost:80"
      }
    ]
  }
```

With this conf when debugging it will open chrome an you will have the browser console in VSC debug console

Comment: VSCode can display browser console, well, Edge at least, maybe Chrome since Edge and Chrome are just Chromium with different lipstick. Not sure about Firefox,

Comment: This is what is said, it's in browser console or in VSC debug console

Comment: no, you didn't mention any ability to see the browser console directly in VScode

Comment: Apology for the misunderstood I don't even know that is was possible and why doing this instead of remote debug ?